# Двумерный массив. Поиск повторяющихся значений

Tags: c#

Функция ищет по матрице 10х10  5 одинаковых в строке или в колонке и по главной диагонали.Вся проблема в то  по диагонали нет результата.

Он все  записывает в том же порядке что по диагонали.
Аналогичные проверки по вертикали и горизонтали хорошо работают.Тут уже не пойму в чем прикол.
Вся функция целиком
//////

```
public bool isWin(string index, string value, bool isNew)
            {
                if (isNew == true)
                    F();
                ///Переменные
                int counter = 0;
                //Листы со значениями
                var vertical      = new List<string>();
                var horizontal    = new List<string>();
                var di            = new List<string>();
                ///
                ///Очитска листов перед каждой проверкой
                vertical.Clear();
                horizontal.Clear();
                di.Clear();
                string name = null;
                bool win = false;
                ///
                int j = index.IndexOf("_");
                for (int i = j + 1; i < index.Length; i++)
                {
                    name += index[i];
                }
                int row = int.Parse(name[0].ToString());
                int col = int.Parse(name[1].ToString());

                Ten[row, col] = value;

                ///Добавление в Листы для проверки условия победы
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    vertical.Add(Ten[i, col]);
                }
                ///Заполение горизонатли
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    horizontal.Add(Ten[row, i]);
                }
                ///
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    di.Add(Ten[i, i]);
                }
                //Это проверка что записывается в List
                string R = null;
                foreach (var item in di)
                {
                    R += item + " ";
                }
                MessageBox.Show(R);

                ///Проверка  для горизонатали и вертикали
                for (int i = 0; i < vertical.Count() - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (vertical[i] == vertical[i + 1] && vertical[i] == value)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        if (counter == 4)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        counter = 0;
                }
                counter = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < horizontal.Count() - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (horizontal[i] == horizontal[i + 1] && horizontal[i] == value)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        if (counter == 4)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        counter = 0;
                }
                counter = 0;
                ///Проверка  для главной диагонали
                for (int i = 0; i < di.Count() - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (di[i] == di[i + 1] && di[i] == value)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        if (counter == 4)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                            counter = 0;
                    }
                }
                return win;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, вы имели в виду, что если элементы не совпали по диагонали, тогда обнулить `counter`, а не сразу же, если counter не равен 4.
Сдвиньте else под проверку их равенства.

Иначе у вас `counter` всегда будет равен нулю.

Comment: ща попробую но не умаю что из за этого так как конструкция аналогична проверки по вертикали и горизонтали а они прекрасно работают.

Comment: @Санитариум, так вы посмотрите где вы написали `else counter = 0;` в других местах, и как в случае диагонали

Comment: лол действительно)